# Unable to make data attribute work with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three buttons. when I press button one, line x should toggle,  button two, line y toggles and so on...( using html5's data attribute). Unfortunately I am unable to make this happen as I get an error saying `type error: star.toggle() is not a function` . my code below:

```
<button class= "a" data-p="x"> Button one </button> 
<button class= "a" data-p="y"> Button two </button>
<button class= "a" data-p="z"> Button three </button>


<div class = "x"> Line x </div>
<div class = "y"> Line y </div>
<div class = "z"> Line z </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.a').on('click', function(){
         var star= $(this).attr('data-p');
         (star).toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what you want to do?

See the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb6ypjsq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.a').on('click', function(){
         var star= $(this).data('p');
         $('.' + star).toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Sure. Because your code was trying to find an element by tag. So, i change it to find elements with the class. You i'll never find an "x", "y" or "z" element :)

Comment: You are welcome. And consider also that I use `$ .data` instead of `$ .attr`.

Comment: Wanted to add an edit. It does work with `$ .data` and ` $ .attr`. Sorry I had a small typo when I was trying again. So both ways are correct.